# Two types of method call

Tags: vimrc

What is the difference between the following two ways of calling a function/method in vimscript?

```
" This seems to always work
call add (events, e)

" This seems to occasionally work
events->add(e)
```

For example, with the latter command, it works when running in the command-line, but when running in a function it returns:

> E492: Not an editor command:                 events->add(e)

It seems pretty inconsistent too, because literally the line above it I am doing:

```
if (all_valid_events->index(e) != -1)   <-- this works   
    events->add(e)                      <-- this fails
```

Additionally, is there a 'name' for the two different type of function calls? Is one preferred over the other (or why are there two different ways, one of which only works about half of the time?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`:help method`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#method).

Global functions can be called as methods on their first argument. But that only works *in an expression*.

When `:call` is used, you need to use normal function syntax.

In Vimscript, functions tyically fit best in expressions, that's probably why the method syntax is only available there. (`:call` is there if you just need to call a function and ignore the result, but expressions are where functions really shine.)

Recent Vimscript has also introduced [`:eval`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aeval), which allows calling a method for its side effects, similarly to `:call`. From `:help :eval`:

> Evaluate `{expr}` and discard the result. The expression is supposed to have a side effect, since the resulting value is not used.  This is similar to `:call` but works with any expression.

The method syntax can be really useful when you have 4 or 5 chained function calls. `:help method` has a good example of that:

```
mylist->filter(filterexpr)->map(mapexpr)->sort()->join()
```

Compare that with the equivalent:

```
join(sort(map(filter(mylist, filterexpr), mapexpr)))
```

Note that the method syntax was introduced to Vim quite recently (set of patchsets around 8.1.18xx), so if you care about compatibility with older versions of Vim (even as recent as Vim 8.0 or a not fully patched Vim 8.1), you might want to avoid method syntax as it might not be available.

Comment: that seems pretty odd to me that it only works in expressions! Is one preferred over the other -- it seems like long chaining for readability and lambda expressions for the `->` syntax.

Comment: @David542 it's the same as you can't use `:add(events, e)`, you need a `:call` there. Functions work best in expressions, but `:call` is there if you just need to call one and do nothing with the result. The method syntax can be really useful when you have 4 or 5 function calls. `:help method` has a good example of that.

Comment: It's extremely recent. It requires vim 8.1.18xx (its supports actually spans over several patchs I [see](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/master/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L1228)). As of now, it's only 11 months old. For the moment I'd rather avoid it as I strive for compatibility with older versions of Vim.

Comment: @Mass It might work with `exec` because `exec` will evaluate the expression... But it will have the side effect of executing the result as an Ex command, right?

Comment: @filbranden sorry, my mistake, I meant `:eval` which was specially added for method syntax, although it allows evaluating any expression as a vim script statement.  Confusing, though necessary.

Comment: @Mass Ah, interesting! Thanks for the pointer! I'm not really too excited about vim9 script, I think it will only increase the delta between Vim and NeoVim and ultimately I think NeoVim will be the one that's relevant long term... But we'll see.

Comment: @filbranden note that `:eval` and method syntax are not strictly part of vim9script, but regular vim script

Comment: @Mass Oh interesting! I'll incorporate that into the answer. Thanks for the pointer!